i installed requests module but it gets error when trying use it
when i use pip list in vscode  i found it in modules lis
requests 2.32.3
once try to use it i get

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

i tried to install it again using cmd in windows and it installed but got the same error
tried to upgrade it using pip install requests --upgrade
it didn't work
closed vscode and reopend it and also same error

It sounds like you are installing requests into an installation of python that vscode is not using. You will either have to persuade vscode to use that version of python or install requests into the installation of python that vscode is actually using.

Maybe take a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78843698/10730091

Can you elaborate your question, are you using venv or using global intepreter.

One suggestion I could give is to use the same virtual environment where you install a requests module.

You can try using the interactive Python shell in your CMD to verify your installation.
In the same CMD where you executed pip list, run python or python3, and then try the following:
import requests

If this works without any issues, I'd like to clarify something important:
The Python environment used when you run code via the "Run" option in the VSCode menu might not be the same as the one used in the VSCode terminal.

This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.
You could check your python version in VSCode by shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.
You could also use command pip install requests in the interpreter which shows  ModuleNotFound error after running your python scripts.
